# Extract the formula of a conditional format in a cell using actxserver MATLAB

Tags: excel, vba, matlab

Can someone help me to extract formula of a conditional format of a entire column?

I tried to get the `FormatConditions` object, I can get the count of conditional formulas, but unable to get the formulas.

MATLAB:

[image: MATLAB command]

Conditonally formatted excel file:

[image: Conditonally formatted excel file]

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer by myself.

```
excel_obj = actxserver('Excel.Application');
    excel_obj.Visible = 0;
    excel_obj.Application.DisplayAlerts = 0;
    source_workbook = excel_obj.Workbooks.Open(source_file);
    target_workbook = excel_obj.Workbooks.Open(target_file);
    source_sheet_outport = source_workbook.Worksheets.Item('Outport');
    range_obj = source_sheet_outport.Range('A2');
    % To get the count.
    count_val = range_obj.FormatConditions.Count
    for ii = 1:count_val
        formula = range_obj.item(ii).Formula1;
    end
```